# How do I write overloaded functions in VB.NET that will all use the same core code?

Tags: vb.net, overloading

I want to write two overloaded functions in VB.NET.

Most of the logic in the two functions will be the same so I don't want to just duplicate the entire function for the two overloads.

I could achieve this by having each overloaded function call another function (that contains the core logic) with optional parameters, like this:

```
Public Overloads Function GetLocationDetails(ByVal countryId As Integer) As LocationInfo
    Return _GetLocationDetails(countryId)
End Function

Public Overloads Function GetLocationDetails(ByVal countryId As Integer, ByVal stateId As Integer) As LocationInfo
    Return _GetLocationDetails(countryId, stateId)
End Function

' This is the function providing the core logic for the two overloaded functions
Private Function _GetLocationDetails(ByVal countryId As Integer, Optional ByVal stateId As Integer = 0) As LocationInfo
    Dim returnVal As New LocationInfo

    Using con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("myConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name, population FROM locations WHERE countryId = @countryId"
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@countryId", countryId))

            ' If there is a stateId, this function was called by the overloaded function that has a stateId parameter, so add that to the query
            If stateId <> 0 Then
                cmd.CommandText &= " AND stateId = @stateId"
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@stateId", stateId))
            End If

            con.Open()
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If dr.Read Then
                    returnVal.Name = dr("name")
                    returnVal.Population = dr("population")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return returnVal
End Function

Public Class LocationInfo
    Public Name As String
    Public Population As Integer
End Class
```

But using optional parameters doesn't seem very elegant and seems to negate the whole purpose of overloading the functions in the first place.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not just use the optional parameters version and drop the other two? Using optional parameters is a whole lot more elegant than making piles of redundant nested overloaded Function definitions.

Comment: That would definitely save a lot of typing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to mention:

First: The function with optional parameters is private, while the fixed-parameter versions are public. This is a huge difference

Second: You could make `stateId` in `_GetLocationDetails` mandatory and use

```
Public Overloads Function GetLocationDetails(ByVal countryId As Integer) As LocationInfo
    Return _GetLocationDetails(countryId,0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Eugen, the reason for the function with optional params being private is because I don't want to expose the core logic, just the two overloads functions that call it. Good call with the passing the zero as the 2nd param to get rid of the optional params - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you're accomplishing with this code. You may as well just get rid of the two public functions and change your private function to public:

```
Public Function _GetLocationDetails(ByVal countryId As Integer, _
                                    Optional ByVal stateId As Integer = 0) _ 
                                    As LocationInfo
```

Comment: IMHO, this is by far the most elegant solution.  The irrational prejudice against optional parameters is just an old C holdover.

Comment: I know I could just make the private function public, I was just trying to explain my question with an example. I've probably over-simplified the code in the example which is why it seems like there's little point overloading the function at all. What I really want to know is, whether there is a way write overloaded functions that utilise the same core logic without them both calling another function that uses optional params. The answer by @EugenRieck is more what I was after. Thanks though for your input.